# Nvidia GPU not showing as Compute Device for Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a question concerning my GPU Cycles Compute Device.

I am running MacBook Pro 10.12.5 with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650 M.

I have done my research a bit and stumbled upon a confusing area. I wanted to speed up my rendering by using my GPU. So I opened my user preferences expecting to find the CUDA interface option, but instead found an option labeled OpenCL.

So upon this confusion I decide to head over to the good ole blender documentation and I learned that 1. OpenCL is supposed to be for AMD graphics cards, which I do not have. I also learn that there is a select list of GeForce cards that support CUDA. So I decide to open that list up, and in fact, my NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M is indeed on the list.

So can someone explain to me why my Blender is saying I have an AMD card and not giving me the CUDA option for my Compute Device?

Thanks for the help.

Chris

Comment: it used to show up for me but since a few updates ago it does not anymore... i thought it was a problem with my GPU

Comment: GPU acceleration support on MAC platforms is not very solid I hear. Are you sure you are not seeing OpenCL listed in the Opensubdivide list? OpenCL is also used for acceleration of OpenSubdivide and in the Compositor for image processing

Comment: http://imgur.com/rWmInUY

Comment: Reference photo of my user preferences showing OpenCL in my compute devices.

Comment: Anybody have any clues to this issue?